# Steinhart-Hart thermistor calibration in Sympy

Tags: python, matrix, sympy, symbolic-math, calibration

Based on [Steinhart-Hart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhart%E2%80%93Hart_equation) equation of thermistor model I have simple 3-point code for NTC thermistor calibration:

```py
from sympy import *

var('R1 R2 R3')
var('T1 T2 T3')
var('A  B  C')

#Ametherm DG103395
T1,R1 = 273.150,31991.6
T2,R2 = 323.150, 3641.0
T3,R3 = 373.150,  686.2

equations = [
    Eq( A + B*ln(R1) + C*ln(R1)**3 , 1.0/T1 ),
    Eq( A + B*ln(R2) + C*ln(R2)**3 , 1.0/T2 ),
    Eq( A + B*ln(R3) + C*ln(R3)**3 , 1.0/T3 ),
]

print solve(equations, (A,B,C))
```

Ideally it should be generalized to multi-point in **minimalistic** matrix form like

```py
T = Matrix([ 273.150, 323.150, 373.150, ....])
R = Matrix([1991.6,  3641.0,   686.2,   ....])
K = MatrixSymbol('K', 3, 1)

print solve( Eq( [1,ln(?),ln(?)**3]*K - 1/T]) )
```

It is very simple to extend original code by create equations in the loop. But it looks very gray.

Is it exist clean and proper matrix way to do it?

**UPDATE:**
It seems that I found solution by myself. Perhaps it can be reduced more?

```
from sympy import *

#Ametherm DG103395
T = Matrix([  273.150,   298.150, 323.150,  373.150, ])
R = Matrix([31991.6,   10000.0,  3641.0,   686.2,    ])

M = Matrix.vstack( *R.applyfunc( lambda x: Matrix([[1, ln(x), ln(x)**3]]) ) )

ABC = M.solve_least_squares( T.applyfunc(lambda x: 1/x) )

print ABC
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to write it, not with matrices but just with lists:

```
from sympy import *

T = [273.150, 323.150, 373.150]
R = [31991.6, 3641.0, 686.2]
n = len(T)
assert n == len(R), "R and T need to have the same length"

A, B, C = symbols("A B C", real=True)

equations = [ Eq( A + B*ln(R[i]) + C*ln(R[i])**3 , 1.0/T[i] ) for i in range(n) ]
print (solve(equations, (A,B,C)))
```

Output: `{A: 0.00115679797363983, B: 0.000227813584600384, C: 1.26349943638314e-7}`

Note that you don't need to declare T and R as SymPy symbols. They are constants and converted automatically when SymPy encounters them in a mixed formula.

Comment: Loop - that is exactly what I don want to do ;) Where is matrix way?

Comment: A matrix is just a loop in disguise. Not sure why you would prefer a matrix? To build the matrix you would again need one or more loops.

Comment: Newer say newer... try applyfunction()

Comment: applyfunction is not a matrix operation, it is just a complicated way to write a loop

Comment: IMHO function applied to matrix is matrix operation. Matrix itself is complicated way to write loops ;) ... bit offtopic. Question is not only_matrix operation. Question is no loops in equations declaration.